# Finding a current through a short circuit (Thevenin)

Tags: current-source, short-circuit, thevenin, superposition

I am working through a question that involves superposition. I have attached a picture of the question I am working through. I am having difficulty doing question e) and f). I was hoping you someone could please give me help me in doing question e).

I initially thought that the answer would simply be the value of the current source, or zero, but both of these answers are wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thank you very much for you time,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mTrV.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot the extra current contribution from the voltage source, through R1, through the shorted output. Both have to be added together.